# I want to create docx file from XML string that I receive from an API with ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, xml, webapi, openxml-sdk, asp.net-core-6.0

This is my xml file that I get this from docx file that I zipped.

This is the document.xml:

```
<w:document 
xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" 
xmlns:cx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2014/chartex" 
xmlns:cx1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/9/8/chartex" 
xmlns:cx2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2015/10/21/chartex" 
xmlns:cx3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/9/chartex" 
xmlns:cx4="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/10/chartex" 
xmlns:cx5="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/11/chartex" 
xmlns:cx6="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/12/chartex" 
xmlns:cx7="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/13/chartex" 
xmlns:cx8="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/5/14/chartex" 
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
xmlns:aink="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2016/ink" 
xmlns:am3d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2017/model3d" 
xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" 
xmlns:oel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2019/extlst" 
xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" 
xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" 
xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" 
xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" 
xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" 
xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" 
xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" 
xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" 
xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" 
xmlns:w16cex="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2018/wordml/cex" 
xmlns:w16cid="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2016/wordml/cid" 
xmlns:w16="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2018/wordml" 
xmlns:w16sdtdh="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2020/wordml/sdtdatahash" 
xmlns:w16se="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2015/wordml/symex" 
xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" 
xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" 
xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" 
xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" 
mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 w16se w16cid w16 w16cex w16sdtdh wp14">
<w:body>
<w:p w14:paraId="59E8928B" w14:textId="4F989F00" w:rsidR="00E57A39" w:rsidRPr="008F41DD" w:rsidRDefault="008F41DD" w:rsidP="008F41DD">
<w:pPr>
<w:pStyle w:val="ListParagraph"/>
<w:numPr>
<w:ilvl w:val="0"/>
<w:numId w:val="1"/>
</w:numPr>
<w:rPr>
<w:rFonts w:cs="B Nazanin"/>
</w:rPr>
</w:pPr>
<w:r w:rsidRPr="008F41DD">
<w:rPr>
<w:rFonts w:cs="B Nazanin"/>
</w:rPr>
<w:t xml:space="preserve">One </w:t>
</w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p w14:paraId="2D18B139" w14:textId="40831F20" w:rsidR="008F41DD" w:rsidRPr="008F41DD" w:rsidRDefault="008F41DD" w:rsidP="008F41DD">
<w:pPr>
<w:pStyle w:val="ListParagraph"/>
<w:numPr>
<w:ilvl w:val="0"/>
<w:numId w:val="1"/>
</w:numPr>
<w:rPr>
<w:rFonts w:cs="B Nazanin"/>
</w:rPr>
</w:pPr>
<w:r w:rsidRPr="008F41DD">
<w:rPr>
<w:rFonts w:cs="B Nazanin"/>
</w:rPr>
<w:t>Two</w:t>
</w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p w14:paraId="4E1C2299" w14:textId="45351C9E" w:rsidR="008F41DD" w:rsidRPr="008F41DD" w:rsidRDefault="008F41DD" w:rsidP="008F41DD">
<w:pPr>
<w:pStyle w:val="ListParagraph"/>
<w:numPr>
<w:ilvl w:val="0"/>
<w:numId w:val="1"/>
</w:numPr>
<w:rPr>
<w:rFonts w:cs="B Nazanin"/>
</w:rPr>
</w:pPr>
<w:r w:rsidRPr="008F41DD">
<w:rPr>
<w:rFonts w:cs="B Nazanin"/>
</w:rPr>
<w:t>Three</w:t>
</w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p w14:paraId="07C809C6" w14:textId="10C92B2E" w:rsidR="008F41DD" w:rsidRPr="008F41DD" w:rsidRDefault="008F41DD" w:rsidP="008F41DD">
<w:pPr>
<w:pStyle w:val="ListParagraph"/>
<w:numPr>
<w:ilvl w:val="0"/>
<w:numId w:val="1"/>
</w:numPr>
<w:rPr>
<w:rFonts w:cs="B Nazanin"/>
</w:rPr>
</w:pPr>
<w:r w:rsidRPr="008F41DD">
<w:rPr>
<w:rFonts w:cs="B Nazanin"/>
</w:rPr>
<w:t>Four</w:t>
</w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p w14:paraId="2DB3ADA1" w14:textId="2F165FEA" w:rsidR="008F41DD" w:rsidRPr="008F41DD" w:rsidRDefault="008F41DD" w:rsidP="008F41DD">
<w:pPr>
<w:rPr>
<w:rFonts w:cs="B Nazanin"/>
</w:rPr>
</w:pPr>
</w:p>
<w:p w14:paraId="086A6010" w14:textId="77777777" w:rsidR="008F41DD" w:rsidRPr="008F41DD" w:rsidRDefault="008F41DD" w:rsidP="008F41DD">
<w:pPr>
<w:rPr>
<w:rFonts w:cs="B Nazanin"/>
</w:rPr>
</w:pPr>
</w:p>
<w:sectPr w:rsidR="008F41DD" w:rsidRPr="008F41DD">
<w:pgSz w:w="12240" w:h="15840"/>
<w:pgMar w:top="1440" w:right="1440" w:bottom="1440" w:left="1440" w:header="720" w:footer="720" w:gutter="0"/>
<w:cols w:space="720"/>
<w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/>
</w:sectPr>
</w:body>
</w:document>
```

My project endpoint API and code:

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
[Consumes("application/xml")]
public IActionResult UploadXml([FromBody] XElement xml)
{
    MemoryStream generatedDocument = new MemoryStream();

    using (WordprocessingDocument package = WordprocessingDocument.Create(generatedDocument, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
    {
        var mainPart = package.AddMainDocumentPart();

        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(xml.ToString());

        new Document(doc.OuterXml);
        package.Save();
    }

    var result = generatedDocument.ToArray();

    return File(result, "application/octet-stream", "document.docx");
}
```

Now I want to pass the all this XML as string to OpenXML SDK package but I don't know how.

I searched a lot but I can't solve this problem and I need an example code to show me how to do this.

If anybody has done this before, please share your code with me.

I want to say that I know there is so much docs out there but I should do this fast and I can't read Microsoft bad docs.

Thanks

Comment: What happens when you run your code? And what do you expect to happen?

Comment: I expect  doing `mainPart.Document = new Document(xml.ToString());`  to work, assuming your xml fragment doesn't need other parts in the package.

Comment: when i run this i can download my docx file but when i want to open that its show me that error, and i want to see my word have list of numbers , its mock data i test @PMF

Comment: Yes I try that before but its not worked @rene

Comment: It looks like you have a controller and are trying to post data to a server.  You are making an HTTP connection and it looks like the body of the HTTP message is going to be XML ([Consumes("application/xml")]).  You do not need to use an XML library.  All you need to do is the read the file as text and add the text to the contents of the HTTP client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your created [Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.document.-ctor?view=openxml-2.8.1) instance goes no where in the code you show. If you don't add it to the package you'll end with no content in your document.

Here is the working code with the needed changes made, basically removing the unneeded fiddling with XmlDocument and the unneeded creation of a byte array because File does accept a stream.

```
[HttpPost()]
[Consumes("application/xml")]
public IActionResult UploadXml([FromBody] XElement xml)
{
    MemoryStream generatedDocument = new MemoryStream();

    using (WordprocessingDocument package = WordprocessingDocument.Create(generatedDocument, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
    {
        var mainPart = package.AddMainDocumentPart();

        mainPart.Document = new Document(xml.ToString(SaveOptions.DisableFormatting));
        package.Save();
    }

    generatedDocument.Position = 0; // to start of stream!

    return File(generatedDocument, "application/octet-stream", "document.docx");
}
```

I assume you are aware that if you want the Action to accept an XElement in .Net Core you have to enable the Xml Serializers like so:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
       .AddControllersWithViews( opt => { opt.MaxValidationDepth = 64; })
       .AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
}
```

I also had to set the MaxValidationDepth to a higher value then the default 32.  Doubling worked for the example data.

For completeness here is my curl test command

```
curl --trace con -H"Content-Type: application/xml" -d@worddoc.xml  --output doctest.docx  http://localhost:5000/Home/UploadXml
```

And this is what I end up with:

[image]

Comment: I forgot to reset position `stream.Position = 0` thank you for solving my issue!

Answer (score 0):

All of the Code I Used :

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UploadXml([FromForm] string XmlString, [FromForm] string FileName)
    {
        var mem = new MemoryStream();
        using (WordprocessingDocument package = WordprocessingDocument.Create(mem, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
        {
            MainDocumentPart mainPart = package.AddMainDocumentPart();
            using (Stream stream = mainPart.GetStream())
            {
                byte[] buf = (new UTF8Encoding()).GetBytes(XmlString);
                stream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
            }
            package.Save();
        }
        return File(mem.ToArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", "document.docx");
   }
```

I Have Worked Alot on this , finally i find the way to do this as Below Code:

```
var mem = new MemoryStream();
        using (WordprocessingDocument package = WordprocessingDocument.Create(mem, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
        {
            MainDocumentPart mainPart = package.AddMainDocumentPart();
            using (Stream stream = mainPart.GetStream())
            {
                byte[] buf = (new UTF8Encoding()).GetBytes(request.XmlString);
                stream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);
            }
            package.Save();
        }
```

its Generate file and i can return as File And IActionResult Like Below:

```
return File(mem.ToArray(), "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", "document.docx");
```